# Programming at 32 bit and 64 bit (at both, at Python, at Pycharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, x86, 64-bit, pycharm

I have a problem and I need some help:
I'm writing project at Python, and I'm writing it at two computers: One of 32bit and the second one is 64 bit.
(The files are at my google drive, so this is how can work from both computer [the 64 bit is new, until now I work at both at 32 bit wit no problem...])

**There is a way to work on the same project at both?**
Because Pycharm needs the project interpreter, and until now it was at the same folder at both computers (with the same name), but because now is 32 bit and 64 bit - so the name of the folders are different :( (and I don't know if to change the name can be good idea...)

Can you think about idea how can I work at both computers (on the same project at Pycharm), without change anytime interpreter anytime I change computer.

I'd like to get from ideas....

Thank you!!

Comment: Install 32bit python on the 64 bit machine and use 32bit on both.

Comment: @NickA, I'll try it!! (I'm not sure it work, but I'll try it tomorrow when I'll be with the 64 computer and I'll tell you if it works....) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem could be solved by investing some time in learning how to use [Git](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) / [GitHub](https://github.com/) for managing your code. This will allow you to work on your project from any computer and easily collaborate with others if you need to.

It's not a quick fix, but you'll gain a lot from learning to use these tools that programmers use everyday.

I hope this helps you solve your problem.